# Error: Cannot allocate an object

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I was trying to make an arc but getting the following error:

```
error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'arc'
                 arcItem = new arc(++id, startP, midP, endP);
```

Can you please help me out to solve the error. My code is as follows. I am getting error in cadgraphicsscene.cpp class at mousepress event.

cadgraphicsscene.cpp

```
void CadGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
    {
        // mousePressEvent in the graphicsScene
        if(mouseEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
        {
            switch (entityMode)
            {

            case ArcMode:
                if (mFirstClick)
                {
                    startP = mouseEvent->scenePos();
                    mFirstClick = false;
                    mSecondClick = true;
                }

                else if (!mFirstClick && mSecondClick)
                {
                    midP = mouseEvent->scenePos();
                    mFirstClick = false;
                    mSecondClick = false;
                    mThirdClick = true;
                }

                else if (!mSecondClick && mThirdClick)
                {
                    endP = mouseEvent->scenePos();
                    mThirdClick = false;
                    mPaintFlag = true;
                }

                if (mPaintFlag)
                {
                    arcItem = new arc(++id, startP, midP, endP);
                    itemList.append(arcItem);
                    mUndoStack->push(new CadCommandAdd(this, arcItem));
                    setFlags();
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

arc.h

```
include <QGraphicsItem>

#include "qmath.h"
class arc : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    arc(int, QPointF, QPointF, QPointF);
    arc(int, QLineF, QLineF);


    virtual void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                       QWidget *widget);
    enum { Type = UserType + 6 };
    int type() const;
    int id;

    QPointF startP, midP, endP, p1, p2, p3,center;
    QLineF lineBC;
    QLineF lineAC;
    QLineF lineBA;
    QLineF lineOA;
    QLineF lineOC;
    QLineF bisectorBC;
    QLineF bisectorBA;
    QGraphicsEllipseItem *ellipse;
    qreal rad;

private:
    QVector<QPointF> stuff;

};
```

Comment: you need to override [boundingRect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect) pure virtual member function as well, not only the `paint` one

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you. Can you explain me with the help of example that how can I do that ?

Comment: declare a member function in your `arc` class declaration: `virtual QRectF boundingRect() const;` and add proper implementation

Comment: Thanks it helped me out too solve the error :)

Answer (score 1):

Its Obvious we cant instantiate Abstract class as in error message. Check out the definition of arc, it must have pure virtual function, derieve a class (with desired members) from it and make object of that class.

Comment: I have added the .h file of arc the arc has same defination as in the .h we can see. Can you please help me to solve the prob.

Comment: Have you implemented `arc.cpp`?

Comment: arc doesnot seem to have pure virtual function, its possibly in public QObject or public QGraphicsItem. Find it and override it